# Plugin development Craft CMS 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am new to craft and I need help to understand how plugins work.
I am trying inject these functions to the `CraftVariable`

```
{% for item in craft.plugin.exampleFunction(test).hide("noTitle") %}
```

`craft.plugin.exampleFunction(test)` is working perfectly 
but `.hide()` is not. Can anybody tell me how to call this function?

Comment: Could you tell us what you want to achieve? What does your `exampleFunction` return?  It should be an object with the function `hide` in it

Comment: Do you have any sample for similer?

Comment: Since I don't know you want to do I can't really provide any help. I can create a simple example but that won't help you

Comment: I just need to know how to access hide function as my exampleFunction is returning array. What changes i need to make here?

Comment: What should your hide function be? what should it do?

Comment: okay Let me explain the scanerio: my example function is returning a custom array. and I want to filter records(array) if any custom fields value is blank

Comment: also put sorting on records similer to craft.plugin.exampleFunction(test).hide("noTitle").sort('price', ASC)

Comment: $query = \craft\elements\Entry::find();
$query->section('products'); 
$tariffSections = $query->all();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussion you'll need to implement a `fetch` function similar like Craft does it with the `ElementCriteriaModel` / `ElementQuery`. So you'll return some kind of search object until you execute the `.find()`/`fetch()` (or whatever you like to call it) function

```
class ClassName{

    /** @var array $_searchObjects */
    private $_searchObjects;

    /**
     * @param $something
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function exampleFunction($something){
        $this->_searchObjects = ['test', 'insert', 'your', 'array', 'here'];

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function hide($string){
        // filter your elements
        $this->_searchObjects = ...//

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function find(){
        return $this->_searchObjects;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like

```
{% set elements = craft.plugin.exampleFunction.find() %}
{% set filterElements = craft.plugin.exampleFunction.hide('something').find() %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to be working for me. Thanks again !!.